# "Unable to initialize module" warning after update PHP on CentOS 5.4

Tags: php, centos, installation

After upgrading PHP from 5.1x to 5.2.10, there are a lot of warning when `php -v`:

```
[root@localhost ~]# php -v
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: fileinfo: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20050922, debug=0, thread-safety=0
PHP    compiled with module API=20060613, debug=0, thread-safety=0
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: mcrypt: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20050922, debug=0, thread-safety=0
PHP    compiled with module API=20060613, debug=0, thread-safety=0
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: memcache: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20050922, debug=0, thread-safety=0
PHP    compiled with module API=20060613, debug=0, thread-safety=0
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: mhash: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20050922, debug=0, thread-safety=0
PHP    compiled with module API=20060613, debug=0, thread-safety=0
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: mssql: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20050922, debug=0, thread-safety=0
PHP    compiled with module API=20060613, debug=0, thread-safety=0
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: readline: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20050922, debug=0, thread-safety=0
PHP    compiled with module API=20060613, debug=0, thread-safety=0
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: tidy: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20050922, debug=0, thread-safety=0
PHP    compiled with module API=20060613, debug=0, thread-safety=0
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP 5.2.10 (cli) (built: Nov 13 2009 11:24:03)
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2009 Zend Technologies
```

How can I fix that? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the old modules and install the new. If you installed via yum/rpm then update the packages. If you built PHP yourself then you'll need to build it with those extensions as well.

Answer (score 0):

Even though `memcached` is happily running on the server, it's not accessible from PHP without the PECL extension. Fortunately this is a very easy process; just use the `pecl` command:

```
$ pecl install memcache
```

See: http://www.lullabot.com/articles/installing-memcached-redhat-or-centos